# Update APK from command line using ADB?

Tags: applications, cyanogenmod, updates, adb

I have a phone running [Cyanogenmod](http://www.cyanogenmod.org/), which is an AOSP derivative. It lacks Google Play.

I installed [Textra](http://www.textra.me/) as the messaging app some time ago using `adb install com.textra.apk`. Textra was recently updated to version 2.28, so I need to update the app.

Using  `adb install com.textra.apk` resulted in a `INSTALL_FAILED_ALREADY_EXISTS` (this was expected). Using  `adb install -reinstall com.textra.apk` succeeded, but I still have the down-level version 2.26.

I don't want to uninstall Textra because I'm concerned it might wipe my existing database of text messages.

How do I use ADB to update an app that is already installed?

Comment: For me, `adb install -r foo.apk` always worked. Which ADB version you are using? Maybe there's a more recent one, and maybe yours has some "bug". And you're correct: uninstalling would remove the app data. Work-around: `adb backup -noapk -f foobar.ab com.foobar.app` (just backup data), then `adb uninstall -k com.foobar.app` (just removes the app, keeps the data), followed by `adb install` (with or without `-r`) might do the trick. If the app data got lost: `adb restore foobar.ab` should get it back. // Does any of that work for you, so I shall make it an answer?

Comment: @Izzy, If given the root access, I think replacing the APK be it using file manager or ADB would achieve the same goal.

Comment: @Firelord might do, but might have side-effects. I tried that recently with a system app, and you know what happened :) Well, apart from the real trouble: there might be side-effects (as the lost account in my case). When using that approach, I strongly suggest doing so while booted into recovery.